# How can I prevent a function from being called twice in Select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a function that returns a number  dbo.somefunction(@id INT). Then I have another function that returns a bit.  dbo.returnsbit(@id INT)

This is what my view looks like

```
SELECT dbo.somefunction(id) AS returnIntValue
FROM sometable
```

Ultimately this is what I want to do

```
SELECT dbo.somefunction(id) AS returnIntValue,, dbo.returnsbit(returnIntValue) As BitValue
FROM sometable
```

The trouble is, the second function (dbo.returnsbit) uses the returned value from the first function (dbo.somefunction).  Of course I can do dbo.returnsbit(dbo.somefunction(id)), but that means the first function is called twice resulting in increased overhead.

Comment: Do you have an actual performance issue?  Premature optimization is the biggest rookie mistake.

Comment: In addition to Blam's comment, you need to learn that, in general in SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. You should try to write code that expresses, as cleanly as possible, what you're aiming for and, only if it doesn't meet your performance targets should you start looking into the worst performing parts (this part is actually true for every language really)

Answer (score 4):

Quite often, if you are using user-defined functions in your queries that process many rows the performance of the query drops significantly just because the server has to call the function for each row. In this sense optimizing the query and calling two functions per row instead of three would not change the overall performance much, it will be poor in any case.

If you have a very complex function, where each call of the function takes long time and you expect to call it for a limited number of rows, then it makes sense to optimize the overall number of calls.

In any case, I found this question interesting enough to check my guesses and write my findings.

---

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later you can use `CROSS APPLY`.

```
SELECT
    CA.returnIntValue
    ,dbo.returnsbit(CA.returnIntValue) As BitValue
FROM
    sometable
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT dbo.somefunction(id) AS returnIntValue
    ) AS CA
```

I have checked on SQL Server 2008 that this variant indeed calls `somefunction` only once per row.

Sometimes it is important not just from the performance point of view. You may get different results if the function with side effects is called more times than needed. See example below.

Here is how to confirm that `CROSS APPLY` calls `somefunction` only once per row.

Create a table with few rows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Numbers]([Number] [int] NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Numbers] ([Number])
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
```

Create first function. It will return a random number. A different number each time it is called. It will not use the parameter, but it doesn't matter for this example.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewRnd]
AS
SELECT CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) AS int) AS rnd

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[somefunction] 
(
    @id int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result int;
    SELECT @Result = rnd FROM dbo.ViewRnd;
    RETURN @Result;
END
```

Create a second function. For this example it will simply return the given parameter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[somefunction2]
(
    @id int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result int;
    SELECT @Result = @id;
    RETURN @Result;
END
```

First query with two calls per row:

```
SELECT
    dbo.somefunction(dbo.Numbers.Number) AS f1
    , dbo.somefunction2(dbo.somefunction(dbo.Numbers.Number)) AS f2
FROM dbo.Numbers
;
```

Result set:

```
f1              f2
-1111498263    -1481060640
 1678801669      230929974
 1377897182    -1527788053
 1786076194     -301754441
  734901522     1385475384
 -636644847    -1076939672
 1551114591     -385251162
   32984627    -1214863465
 2075259001    -1450159610
-2063202107    -1023434184
```

You can see that values `f1` and `f2` in each row are different, which means that random number was generated twice for each row, i.e. the function `somefunction` was called twice for each row.

Second query with one call per row:

```
SELECT
    CA.f1
    , dbo.somefunction2(CA.f1) AS f2
FROM
    dbo.Numbers
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT dbo.somefunction(dbo.Numbers.Number) AS f1
    ) CA
;
```

Result set:

```
         f1             f2
 -963307489     -963307489
  450369380      450369380
 1193334688     1193334688
 1480723291     1480723291
-1666937401    -1666937401
 1001969991     1001969991
-1142557574    -1142557574
-1891218324    -1891218324
 -102288163     -102288163
 1575326336     1575326336
```

You can see that values `f1` and `f2` in each row are the same, which means that the function `somefunction` was called only once per row.

Comment: @user79284, was my or other answer useful for you? Please upvote useful answers and accept the answer that was most useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT returnIntValue, dbo.returnsbit(returnIntValue) As BitValue
FROM 
    (SELECT dbo.somefunction(id) AS returnIntValue
    FROM sometable) t
```

I guess dbo.somefunction may still be invoked twice on each row depending on the query plan the optimizer happens to pick, as Damien_The_Unbeliever noted.